# ConnectionRefusedError: Selenium Remote WebDriver from Python in Docker

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run a Flask App that runs a web scraper when a certain endpoint is called. Everything is containerized using Docker Compose.

**Docker Compose File**

```
services:

  selenium:
    image: seleniarm/standalone-chromium  # using this because I'm on M1
    hostname: local
    volumes:
      - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
    ports:
      - '4444:4444'

  api:
    build: api
    restart: always
    hostname: local
    environment:
      - environment=Local
    depends_on:
      - selenium
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    command: ["gunicorn", "-w", "3", "-t","300", "-b", "0.0.0.0:80", "app:app"]
```

**Dockerfile for API**

```
FROM python:3.8
COPY . /api
WORKDIR /api
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 4444 # not sure if this is necessary?
```

**Sample Python Function** (this is called by a Flask route, which I know is configured properly

```py
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time


def test_webdriver():
    logger.info("Beginning to test webdriver")
    ua = UserAgent()
    user_agent = ua.random
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
    options.add_argument('--verbose')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-logging'])
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
        options=options
    )
    driver.get('https://github.com')
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()
    return
```

Errors:

```
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xffffaff19490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Which eventually throws...

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=4444): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xffffaff19490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I'm assuming that for some reason my `api` container isn't able to reach my `selenium` container. I verified that visiting `http://localhost:4444` returns the Selenium Grid UI, so I know the container is up and running. Any idea why the API can't find it?

Answer (score 1):

That is probably got to do with your Docker set up. You need to ensure that selenium and api services have access to the same Docker network. You can do that by adding at the root level of your docker-compose file:

```
networks:
  flaskapp:
    driver: bridge
```

and also adding this network to both the services e.g.

```
  selenium:
    image: seleniarm/standalone-chromium
    hostname: local
    volumes:
      - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
    ports:
      - '4444:4444'
    networks:
      - flaskapp  # This is what you need to add
```

and the same for your api service.